# Get Squid to pass X-Requested-With header

Tags: proxy, configuration, squid, http-headers

I have configured a `squid 3.1` proxy server.
Everything works great except for the `X-Requested-With` header. 
I can't manage to figure out how to pass that header to the site I'm attempting to open via the proxy.

This is my current configuration:

```
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access All deny all #remove all other headers


# delete "x-forwarder-for.." headers
forwarded_for delete
request_header_access Via deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
```

I tried to add this line `request_header_access X-Requested-With allow all` to the configuration but apparently `X-Requested-With` is an unknown header name...
Apparently I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request_header_access` requires `--enable-http-violations` to be specified when you build squid. Check its presence.

**Update**

Also the [documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_access/) states:

> By default, all headers are allowed (no anonymizing is performed).

This means that if a header is not listed anyhow then squid should pass it transparently.

**Update**

If you have some anonymizing set up then you should put all 'allow' rules before 'All deny All' rule

Comment: @tftd Does the client actually send this header?

Comment: Yes the client sends it in ajax requests via `XMLHttpRequest`. You can't enable `http-violations` in `3.1` because it's endabled by default. I've updated my question (there was a missing line). If I remove the line `request_header_access All deny all` it works fine, but then the proxy becomes transparent and that's not what I need.

Comment: The configuration I've posted in the question shows all of the rules are before `request_header_access All deny all` :)

Comment: @tftd But it does not list your 'X-Requested-With'

Comment: If you read the bottom of the question you'll see I have stated squid returns an error `unknown header name` when I add `request_header_access X-Requested-With allow all`.

Comment: @tftd yes, I did. But I missed that you are using 3.1. if you could switch to 3.2 then your problem will be solved as documentation states that since 3.2 you may use custom headers.

Comment: Apparently upgrading to the 3.2 version fixed the problem. Thanks for the help :)